# Get a single instance of IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using this code and it works

```
@model IEnumerable<MyLibrary.Type.Variable>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @item.Date.LocalDateTime.ToShortDateString()
}
```

but I only need one instance of this, not a foreach/multiple. I use the foreach later on in the view to populate a table. That's why I took the foreach logic here.  Instead of displaying the date multiple time I just need it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Model.First() to get 1 object from the ienumerable

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
@Model.FirstOrDefault().ToShortDateString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@Model.FirstOrDefault().Date.LocalDateTime.ToShortDateString()
```